# Get notification from supervisord when a job exits

Tags: logging, monitoring, supervisord

Is there any way `supervisord` can automatically restart a failed/exited/terminated job **and** send me a notification email with a dump of the last x lines of log file?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

There is a plugin called superlance.

You install it with `pip install superlance` or download it at: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/superlance

The next thing you do is you go into your `supervisord.conf` and add the following lines:

```
[eventlistener:crashmail]
command=/usr/local/bin/crashmail -a -m email1@example.com
events=PROCESS_STATE
```

This should be followed by a "supervisorctl update". When a process "exits" you will now get a notification sent to email1@example.com.

If you only want to listen to some selected apps you can exchange the `-a` for a `-p program1` or if it is a group `group1:program2` One example would be

```
[eventlistener:crashmail]
command=/usr/local/bin/crashmail -p program1 -p group1:program2  -m email1@example.com
events=PROCESS_STATE
```

Regarding the automatic restart:
you should make sure that `autorestart` is set to `true` (it is set to `unexpected` by default). This way the package will be restarted 3 times. If after that it still exits, it gives up, but you can change that with `startretries`.

Example program:

```
[program:cat]
command=/bin/cat
autorestart=true
startretries=10
```

Comment: Despite being inactive for a few years this thread is still valid - I just tested superlance 1.0.0 (dated oct 2016) with supervisor 3.1.4 (CentOS7) and the crashmail worked just fine.

Comment: How do we test it?

Comment: If you have it configured correctly, you should see `crashmail` as process when running `supervisorctl`. You can test the mail by doing `ps aux | grep programthatshouldnotcrash`, then killing that process with `kill -9 123456789` where `123456789` is the pid of the program that is currently running via supervisor. Note: The documentation says to listen to `PROCESS_STATE_EXITED` instead of `PROCESS_STATE`.

Comment: And, where do i setup the SMTP for sending the email?

Answer (score 0):

I tried installing superlance and running crashmail like this:

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip
sudo pip install superlance
```

after i do:

```
sudo nano /etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf
```

and after i added:

```
[eventlistener:crashmail]
command=/usr/local/bin/crashmail -a -m mymail@mail.fr
events=PROCESS_STATE
```

and I do not receive anything....

My crashmail file is:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

-- coding: utf-8 --
import re
import sys

from superlance.crashmail import main

if name == 'main':
sys.argv[0] = re.sub(r'(-script.pyw?|.exe)?$', '', sys.argv[0])
sys.exit(main())
```