# Where is crashmail installed on linux?

Tags: supervisord

Long story short I'm trying to get notification from supervisord when job exists . I've been following this: [Get notification from supervisord when a job exits](https://serverfault.com/questions/241721/get-notification-from-supervisord-when-a-job-exits).

My problem is that I've install `superlance` but when I run `supervisorctl` I get the error:

`crashmail                        FATAL     can't find command '/usr/local/bin/crashmail'`.

I then navigate to `/usr/local/bin/crashmail` and indeed, `crashmail` is not there. However when I run `pip freeze` I can see that `superlance` is installed. Does that mean `crashmail` is installed elsewhere? If so where is it? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If crashmail is installed and in your `$PATH` you can find it by running

```
command -v crashmail
```

otherwise you will have to find out if it's installed and where. Once you figure that out, you can tell supervisor where to find the crashmail executable.